# How to implementing beforeDestroy methods in SailsJS?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm new using sails JS.

I have methods like this

```
beforeDestroy: function(borrow, next){
        return Book.find({id:borrow.product})
        .then(function(){
            Book.update(borrow.product, {'isBorrowed' : false})  
        })
        .then(function(){
            next();
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            next(error);
        });
    }
```

When I tried to destroy data book 'IsBorrowed' still true, how to fix this when tried t delete data, firstly find id and secondly, change data book IsBorrowed to be false? Thank Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution (to your original question - just switch the isBorrowed logic around as you now need it):

book.js

```
module.exports = {

  schema: true,
  attributes: {
    name: {type: 'string', required: true},
    desc: {type: 'text'},
    isBorrowed: {type: 'boolean', defaultsTo: false}
  }

};
```

bookBorrowed.js

```
module.exports = {

  schema: true,

  attributes: {
    book: {model: 'Book'}
  },

  beforeDestroy: function (criteria, next) {

    var bookId = criteria.where.id;
    console.log(bookId);

    Book.update({id: bookId}, {isBorrowed: true})
      .exec(function (err, updatedBook) {
        if (err) {
          next('no book..');
        }
        console.log('updated book', updatedBook);
        next();
      });
  }

};
```

Your problem was that you should consider the relationship with id, not object.
Also, the criteria parameter passed into beforeDestroy has a where object, it isn't the model. Also, the update() function takes an object criteria, see above.

If you wish to test, replace your bootstrap.js with the following snippet:

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {

  var bk = {name: 'name', desc: 'desc', isBorrowed: false};

  Book.create(bk).exec(function (err, book) {
    if (err) {
      cb(err);
    }
    console.log('book: ', book);
    var bb = {book: book.id};
    BookBorrowed.create(bb).exec(function (err, bkBorrowed) {
      if (err) {
        cb(err);
      }
      console.log('bkBorrowed: ', bkBorrowed);
      BookBorrowed.destroy({id: bkBorrowed.id}).exec(function (err, bkBorrowed) {
        if (err) {
          cb(err);
        }
        cb();
      });
    })
  });

};
```